# More Elegant Way of Reading XML data

Tags: android, xml

In my Android application, I am using a raw XML file to store certain data and then read it in an Activity.

Lets us say the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to> Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

In the activity, I am reading this data using  XMLDOMParser within a node loop and then comparing it to another string like this:

```
         String fromAddress = parser.getValue(e, "from");
         if(fromAddress.equals("Jani")) {
              // do something for Jani
            }
```

This works fine. However this ceases to compare the string, as soon as the format of XML file changes.

For instance, if instead of `<from>Jani</from>` I add line breaks like

```
<from>
   Jani
</from>
```

the above if conditional fails to compare correctly.

Some how not feeling comfortable relying on specific XML formatting in the code. What is a better way to handle this kind of scenario.

Comment: you can use xmlpullparser. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Comment: xmlpullparser code is too complicated for implementing the several levels of nesting in my particular use case. i tried implementing it but after several hours i moved to XMLDOMParser

Comment: i find xml pull parser easier well its left to you to decide and also why not trim() as suggested by @Selvin?

Comment: Oops I was under the impression that trim only removes white spaces. that was stupid of me..Thanks a lot :)

Comment: maybe your parser library(as you did not point which library you are using and quick google for "XMLDOMParser android" do not return any library or documentation) have option to normalize/preserve whitespaces, too